# pythonで画像上の建造物を物体として認識させたい

Tags: python, python3, windows, opencv, 画像

画像上の特定の部分をオブジェクトとして認識させたい

具体的には、画像の空（そら）の部分との差分として、建造物を物体として認識できるようにし対と思っています。（空の領域に重なっていない物体は認識しない）
物体として認識することによって、例えばグラフなどを上に重ねたときにグラフと物体の交点が得られるような処理をおこないたいと思っています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プログラミング言語：python3.6
開発環境：Winpython - Spyder
OS:Windows7

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/150949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マルチポスト先で回答をいただきました。
よって、自己解決とさせていただきます。

回答内容：
Deep Learning の SegNet というモデルを使い、画像を領域ごとに分割させる。